# Prove that if $g^2=e$ for all $g$ in $G$ then $G$ is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Prove that if $g^2=e$ for all $g$ in $G$ then $G$ is Abelian.

This question is from group theory in Abstract Algebra and no matter how many times my lecturer teaches it for some reason I can't seem to crack it.

(Please note that $e$ in the question is the group's identity.)

Here's my attempt though...

First I understand Abelian means that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are elements of a group $G$ then they are Abelian if $g_1g_2=g_2g_1$...

So, I begin by trying to play around with the elements of the group based on their definition...

$$(g_2g_1)^r=e$$ 
$$(g_2g_1g_2g_2^{-1})^r=e$$
$$(g_2g_1g_2g_2^{-1}g_2g_1g_2g_2^{-1}...g_2g_1g_2g_2^{-1})=e$$

I assume that the $g_2^{-1}$'s and the $g_2$'s cancel out so that we end up with something like,

$$g_2(g_1g_2)^rg_2^{-1}=e$$
$$g_2^{-1}g_2(g_1g_2)^r=g_2^{-1}g_2$$

Then ultimately...

$$g_1g_2=e$$

I figure this is the answer. But I'm not totally sure. I always feel like I do too much in the pursuit of an answer when there's a simpler way.

Reference: Fraleigh p. 49 Question 4.38 in *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*.

Comment: What does r stand for?

Comment: I don't think we can assume that $ g_2 g_1 $ has finite order , with $(g_2g_1)^r=e $

Answer (score 58):

Hint: Take $(ab)^2=1$ and multiply both sides on the right with $b$, then again on the right with $a$.

Answer (score 46):

For *any* $g, h \in G$, consider the element $g\cdot h\cdot h\cdot g.~$
Since $g^2 = g\cdot g= e$ for all $g \in G$, we find that
$$g\cdot h\cdot h\cdot g = g\cdot(h\cdot h)\cdot g = g\cdot e\cdot g = g\cdot g = e.$$
But, $g\cdot h$ has *unique* inverse element $g\cdot h$, while we have just proved that $(g\cdot h)\cdot (h\cdot g) = e$, and so it must be that $g\cdot h = h\cdot g$ for all $g, h \in G$, that is, $G$ is an abelian group.

Comment: This is the elegant solution to this problem. I thought I'd post this exact solution on here if everyone did it the long way, but I'm half a year late. (+1)

Answer (score 35):

Whenever you have a condition $g^2=e$ in a group, it's  equivalent to $g=g^{-1}$ (multiply both sides by $g^{-1}$).

In this case, it applies to every element of the group, so you can add or remove inverses from any expression freely. So the proof is simply $$ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba.$$

Comment: What happens after the 2nd equality?

Comment: @Dole, 1st equality: addition of an inverse, 2nd equality: formula for inverse of a product, 3rd equality: removal of inverses. Remember in this group, we can add or remove $^{-1}$ from anything, because every element is its own inverse. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 11):

**Hint**: Note that $g_1g_2=g_2g_1$ if and only if $g_1g_2g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}=e$ (Why?), and that $g^{-1}=g$ for all $g\in G$ (Why?).

Answer (score 11):

Then for all $a,b \in G$: $$ab = (bb)ab(aa) = b(baba)a = ba.$$

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, the map $$\begin{align*}f:G&\rightarrow G\\x&\mapsto x^{-1}(=x)\end{align*}$$ is an automorphism of $G$ and so $G$ is Abelian!

Comment: This is actually quite neat! There is no circular logic either, which I was initially worried about. (Also, I've edited the post to make the map clearer. Feel free to undo my edit if you wish.)

Comment: @user1729: .This time it looks good. Thanks  for the edit!

Comment: best answer by far.

Answer (score 10):

Proof: let for all $a,b$ in group $G$. 
claim that To show $ab=ba$ a commutative. 
By using a fact that $a\cdot a=b\cdot b=(ab)\cdot(ab)=e$.
since $(ab)^2=a^2\cdot b^2=e\cdot e=e$. We have $ab\cdot ab=e$. Multiplying on the right by $ba$, we obtain
\begin{align}
ab\cdot ab\cdot ba &= e\cdot ba\\
ab\cdot a(b\cdot b)\cdot a &= ba\\
ab\cdot a\cdot b^2\cdot a &=\\
ab\cdot a\cdot e\cdot a &=\\
ab\cdot a\cdot a &=\\
ab\cdot e &=\\
ab &= ba,
\end{align}
for all $a,b$ in $G$. since $G$ is abelian group. This is proved last.

Comment: I think you meant "therefore" instead of "since" in the last sentence. That $G$ is abelian was to be proved, not given (and BTW, nowhere you've used that it is specifically a group; the argumentation works just as well for monoids that are not groups).

Answer (score 7):

Another proof is by contradiction.

Let G be a group with operation *. You want to show that:
$(\forall g \in G:g^2=e)\implies(G\text{ Abelian}\Leftrightarrow \forall x,y \in G: x*y = y*x)$.

(where $g^2$ is shorthand for $g*g$)

Suppose by contradiction that the group is not Abelian, i.e. that ($\exists x,y\in G: x*y\neq y*x)$. Now multiply on the left by $x$ and on the right by $y$.

You get $x^2*y^2 \ne (xy)^2$. But then it means that $e*e \neq e$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Hi, I know this is old, but how can you multiply the left side by $x$ and right side by $y$ and not do the same for both sides? In other words, if I multiply one side by $x$, don't I have to do the same for the other side? I am not sure if I am reading that correctly.

Comment: $\color{red}{x} *x*y*\color{red}{y} \neq \color{red}{x} * y * x * \color{red}{y} $, so to be precise I should have said multiple both sides on the left by $x$ and on the right by $y$. Then applying associativity ($*$ is associative by definition of group) you get $(\color{red}{x} *x)*(y*\color{red}{y}) \neq (\color{red}{x} * y) * (x * \color{red}{y})$ and there you go. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding to an old post and for the clarification!

Answer (score 6):

By construction:

$\quad\begin{align*}
(ab)(ab) &= e = a(bb)a \\
\require{cancel}\cancel{(ab)}(ab) &= \cancel{(ab)}(ba) \qquad\text{by associativity followed by cancellation}\\
ab &= ba
\end{align*}$

Hence, the group is Abelian.

Comment: This is very direct and nice. Is this proof plausible?

Comment: What makes you think this proof may not be plausible?

Comment: How you took associativity property is not clear, as it applies on $4$ elements.

Answer (score 4):

given $g^2=e$ for all $g\in G$
So $g=g^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$
Let,$a,b\in G$
Now $ab=a^{-1}b^{-1}
               =(ba)^{-1}
               =ba$
So $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in G$ .Hence $G$ is Abelian Group.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b\in G$:
\begin{align}
ab\cdot (ab)^{-1} &= ab\cdot b^{-1}a^{-1}\\
&= b\cdot  ba\quad(\because \text{each element is self inverse})\\
&= a(b^{2})a\\
&= a\cdot e\cdot a\\
&= a^{2}\\
&=e
\end{align}
This shows $(ab)^{-1}=ba$. Now $(ab)^2=e$, so $ab\cdot ab=ab\cdot ba=e$, which by the cancellation law gives $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in G$, since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary. Hence $G$ is abelian as required.

Answer (score 2):

$$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=(xyx^{-1})^2x^2(x^{-1}y^{-1})^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$(ab)^{2}=e
$($\because$ $a,b \in G, ab\in G$, due to the closure property of group axiom )$\implies 
(ab)(ab)=e\tag 1$
Pre multiply $a$ on both sides also post multiply $b$ on both sides. The equation (1) becomes,
 $aababb=ab\tag2$($\because$ by associativity and self invertible property.
$ba=ab\tag3$

Answer (score 0):

We have for all $a,b\in G$,

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{abab}&=(ab)^2\\
&=e\\
&=ee\\
&=a^2b^2\\
&=\color{red}{aabb},
\end{align}$$

so that

$$\begin{align}
ba&=e(ba)e\\
&=(a^{-1}a)ba(bb^{-1})\\
&=a^{-1}(\color{red}{abab})b^{-1}\\
&=a^{-1}(\color{red}{aabb})b^{-1}\\
&=(a^{-1}a)ab(bb^{-1})\\
&=e(ab)e\\
&=ab.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Here's an approach using character theory.
Let $\chi\in\text{Irr}(G)$. It suffices to show that $\chi$ is linear. Since $g\mapsto g^2$ is a bijection $G\to G$ it follows
$$\chi(1)^2=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|\chi(1)|^2=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|\chi(g^2)|^2=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|\chi(g)|^2=[\chi,\chi]=1.$$