# Group G with $\left(\forall g \in G: g^2=1_G\right) \implies \text{G is abelian}$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have the following task:

> Be $G$ a group with $\forall g \in G: g^2=1_G$
>
> Prove that $G$ is abelian.

I proved it this way:

$\forall g \in G: g^2=1_G$ implies $\forall g \in G: g=g^{-1}$

Be $g,h \in G$.

It is $gh \in G$ and $(gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}$ since $(g(hh^{-1})g^{-1})=1_G=(h^{-1}(g^{-1}g)h)$

Hence:

$$gh = (gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1} = hg \quad \square$$

This is the first proof with groups I've ever done in my life, hence I am a bit unsure if everything is correct. It would be nice when someone could tell me if my proof is complete.

Comment: This looks good. You don't even need the middle two lines. The demonstration that $g$ = $g^{-1}$ and the last line should do it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252362/prove-that-a-group-g-such-that-every-element-g-in-g-satisfies-the-equality-g

Comment: Your proof is valid. You can also note that gh= g(gh.gh)h=(gg)hg(hh)=hg.