# Assume two natural numbers $m,n$ are coprime such that $a^m b^m=b^m a^m$ and $a^n b^n=b^n a^n$. Then $G$ is an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Assume two natural numbers $m,n$ are coprime (this means $(m,n)=1$) such that for each $a ,b \in G$ we have $a^m b^m = b^m a^m$ and $a^n b^n = b^n a^n$. Then $G$ is an abelian group.

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$ ? What have you tried?

Comment: where are the your comment you use a^m b^m = b^m a^m and a^n b^n = b^n a^n??

Comment: m and n are natural numbers that (m,n)=1

Comment: m and n are co-prime means that (m,n)=1

Comment: @dibak chopra - This is a very good question +1 from me and check my solution here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326702/how-to-prove-that-a-group-with-some-properties-is-abelian/327766#327766

Comment: @Nicky Hekster i read your solution but i confused in those answers and comments.why we have (b^um   a^um)^vn=b^um+vn   a^um+vn??

Comment: @Dibak - I cannot find that in my proof. Aren't you looking at the wrong proof, namely that below mine of vonbrand??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$(m,n)=1$ then there exist $c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $cm+dn=1$. Thus 
$$gh=g^{cm+dn}h^{cm+dn}=g^{cn}g^{dm}h^{cm}h^{dn}=\cdots=h^{cm+dn}g^{cm+dn}=hg.$$
because 
$$(g^mh^n)^{cm}=g^m(h^ng^m)^{cm-1}h^n=g^m(h^ng^m)^{cm}g^{-m}h^{-n}h^n=g^m((h^ng^m)^{c})^mg^{-m}=(h^ng^m)^{cm}$$
Similarly, $(g^mh^n)^{dn}=(h^ng^m)^{dn}$ and so, $h^ng^m=g^mh^n$.

Comment: I can't figure out the details of the dots…

Comment: yes.thus i ask farhad about ... and where are the answer use a^m b^m = b^m a^m and a^n b^n = b^n a^n

Comment: hi. from the blank three dot.(...).

Comment: @farhad what is  your way to solution?

Comment: i complete the answer.