# what is the way to reach apropriate answer about my question about group in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Assume there exist **$2$ natural numbers** that are coprime ($m$ and $n$ such that $(m,n)=1$) such that for each $g$, $h \in G$ we have $g^m h^m = h^m g^m$ and $g^n h^n = h^n g^n$. Then $G$ is abelian group. (That means $ab=ba$.)
>
> Hint: $(m,n)=1$ then there exist $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $cm+dn=1$. thus
> $$gh = g^{cm+dn}  h^{cm+dn} = g^{cm}  g^{dn}  h^{cm}  h^{dn} = (g^m)^c  (g^n)^d  (h^m)^c  (h^n)^d = (g^n)^d  (g^m)^c  (h^m)^c  (h^n)^d$$
> Use property in hypothesis to reach $gh=hg$.

Please help me to continue.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: you need to show that $g^{nd}h^{nd}=h^{nd}g^{nd}$ and $g^{cm}h^{cm}=h^{cm}g^{cm}$.

Comment: A good way to start is $g^dg^dh^dh^d=g^dh^dg^dh^d=h^dh^dg^dh^d=h^dh^dg^dg^d$.

Comment: are you have simle way to proof?if we have same exponent or assumation in hypothesis we can commute

Comment: Try this $gh = g^{cm+dn}  h^{cm+dn} = g^{dn}  g^{cm}  h^{cm}  h^{dn} = (g^d)^n  (g^c)^m  (h^m)^c  (h^n)^d$.

Comment: here problem is commutative ...what theorems help us to commute elements in group?same exponent?

Comment: we use the same exponent property and show the hint.

Comment: hint that you introduce when it is perform that we are same exponent but in your hint in comment not exist same exponent

Comment: i confused...i read soloution about this problem in here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326702/how-to-prove-that-a-group-with-some-properties-is-abelian/327766#   is there anyone to give me best answer and solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with
$$gh = g^{dn+cm}h^{cm+dn} = (g^d)^n(g^c)^m(h^c)^m(g^d)^n,$$
then apply the identity together with some regrouping.

Comment: You've added nothing to what the OP wrote.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I don't agree. I both reversed the order of summation in the exponent and changed the way things were grouped.