# If $\forall x \in G$ where G is a group $x=x^{-1}$ then how is this group abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

If $\forall x \in G$ where G is a group $x=x^{-1}$ then how is this group abelian .

This question is from Gallian's book where question provides information that G is a group and $\forall x \in G$ , $x=x^{-1}$ then we have to prove that G is abelian , how is it possible ??

Comment: Hint : In such a group, we have $x^2=e$ for all $x\in G$. Now, consider the products $abab$ and $aabb$

Comment: Please [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238171/prove-that-if-g2-e-for-all-g-in-g-then-g-is-abelian) next time before posting.

Answer (score 6):

We wish to show $\forall x,y \in G$, $xy = yx$. Note that $xy \in G \implies xy = (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1} = yx$

Answer (score 2):

We have $ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$