# Proof help: a² = identity -> monoid must be a commutative group

Tags: linear-algebra

> We have a monoid with the identiy $e$, and we know that any element of the monoid squared is the identity. I have to prove now that this is a commutative group.

May somebody help me or give me a hint how I can show that this must be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $a^2 = e$ for all $a$ implies $ab = ba$:

$(ab)(ab) = e$

$a(ab)(ab)b = a*e*b$

$(aa)(ba)(bb) = ab$

$e*ba*e = ab$

$ba = ab$.

or

$ab = k$

$a=abb = kb$

$e = aa = kba$

$k = ke = kkba  = ba$

So $ab = k = ba$

Comment: This proof is very good to follow. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

To show it's a commutative group, you need to show two things:

- Existence of inverses
- Commutativity

For inverses, take any element $a$; $a^2 = e$, so $a$ is its own inverse.

For commutativity, you need to show that for any elements $a,b$, $ab = ba$. Since $a^{-1}=a$ and $b^{-1}=b$, $$ab(ba)^{-1} = aba^{-1}b^{-1}=abab = (ab)^2 = e$$
Thus (multiplying both sides by $ba$ on the right) $ab = ba$

Comment: Can you explain me why (ab)² = e implies ab = ba?

Comment: @RM777 I've edited; is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, appreciate it.

Comment: The idea of the proof is that we assume that (ba)^-1 is the inversed element of ab, right?

Comment: @RM777 We don't assume it; we prove it.

Comment: But wee took advantage of the proposition that there is only one inverse for each element.

Comment: @RM777 Yes. It is a theorem of group theory that inverses are unique. (Actually the proof can be modified so it does not rely on this fact -- first show  $ab$ is an inverse to $ba$, then multiply both sides of $abab=e$ by $ba$.)

Answer (score 0):

$a^2=e$ implies that every $a$ has an inverse, itself. Therefore, this monoid is in fact a group. It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238171/prove-that-if-g2-e-for-all-g-in-g-then-g-is-abelian) that $a^{2}=e$ in a group implies that it is commutative.

Comment: I know that a² = e implies a group. But if I have two elements in the group which are not the same, say a and b. How can i prove that ab = ba with the fact that a² = e?

Comment: "It is well known that $a^2=e$ in a group implies that it is commutative."   Not so well-known that the op knows it.  That probably should be proven.  (Although it'd be fair to ask the OP to figure it out.)

Comment: @RM777, I've added a link to a proof.

Comment: ... $e = (ab)(ab) = (aa)(bb)$ so $a(ab)(ab)b = a(aa)(bb)b$ so $ba = ab$.

Comment: Great thank you!