# Proving that a group is abelian!

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Supposing we have a group $(G,*)$ (Which we don't know the elements of).

It is given that for each $x, y \in G$, exists $x*y*x=y$.

That's the only information we receive, How can we prove that group G is an abelian group?

Comment: As a hint, consider what happens when you take y to be the identity element.

Comment: Do you mean $y^{-1}$ with "$y*$" ?

Comment: @Peter , No. It was a misclick due to me being on the phone instead on the PC. Anyways, I received the answer I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $xyx=y$ for each pair $x,y\in G$ then in particular this is true if we take $y=e$, where $e\in G$ is the netural element. We obtain $x^2=e$ for any $x\in G$, i.e. every element of $G$ is of order $2$. And such groups are abelian as you can [read here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238171/prove-that-if-g2-e-for-all-g-in-g-then-g-is-abelian).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! It really helped me and I finally answered the question.