# Proof verification: $(xy)^2=xy$ for all $x,y$ in a group implies the group is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

> $(xy)^2=xy$ for all $x,y$ in a group implies the group is Abelian

Proof:

$(xy)^2=xy \implies (xy)^{-1}(xy)^2 = (xy)^{-1}(xy) \implies xy = e$ where $e$ is the identity of the group. Since $x,y$ is arbitrary, it is also true that $yx=e$. Hence $yx=xy$. $\square$

Is this proof correct? Thanks

Edit:
This question is from chapter 3 problem 52 of Abstract Algebra Theory and Applications by Judson
[image]

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: This is correct, but the statement you’re proving is somewhat strange. You can determine the group much more precisely than just noting that it is abelian. If this is an exercise: Are you reading it correctly?

Comment: If $xy=e$ for all $x,y$, what can you deduce by putting $y=e$?

Comment: In fact, the group $G$ must be the trivial group.

Comment: The usual formulation (for this exercise) is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238171/prove-that-if-g2-e-for-all-g-in-g-then-g-is-abelian?rq=1). You should clarify this. For $y=e$ it just says $x^2=x$ for all $x$, which is $x=e$ for all $x$. This seems too trivial.

Comment: Note this isn't in the 2021 version (the closest is exercise 51).  Which version of the text are you using?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah... sorry. I’m using the August 27, 2010 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is right, but as Eike Schulte said, it is somehow strange. I strongly suspect your statement was $\forall x\in G, x^2=x$. I'll prove that statement. (In fact, your statement and my statement is equivalent. why?)

> If $x,y\in G$, $$\begin{align} xxyy&=x^2y^2\\ &=xy\\ &=(xy)^2\\ &=xyxy, \end{align}$$ then $xy=yx$.

Comment: More simply: $x^2=x\implies x^{-1}x^2=x^{-1}x\implies x=e$. So the group has only one element (and is therefore abelian).

Answer (score 2):

> **Theorem:** The only idempotent of a group $G$ is the identity $e$.

*Proof:* Suppose $a^2=a\in G$. Then $aa=a=ae$, so, multiplying on the left by $a^{-1}$, we get $a=e$. $\square$

In your question, since $e\in G$, we have $y^2=(ey)^2=ey=y$ for all $y\in G$. Thus $y=e$, so $G$ is trivial and hence abelian.