# Explain this step: "if $gg=e$ and $hh=e$ for all $g,h \in G$ then $(gh)(gh)=e$" (Beginner question)

Tags: group-theory

I don't understand this step (this is from some proof of a lemma from a book):

Let $g$ and $h$ be elements of a group $G$, where all elements are self-inverse.

so $gg = e$ and
$hh = e$.

We can then write:
$(gh)(gh) = e$.

By what operation do we reach this last step?

Comment: You might want to check the specifics of the situation described in the book. You will likely find that you are told that every element of the group has order $2$, as this is a standard beginner exercise. It is not true that the product of involutions (elements of order $2$) is always an involution, nor is it true that all involutions in a general group commute ($S_3$ the non-abelian group of order $6$ is a simple counterexample).

Comment: @MarkBennet My mistake sorry. Indeed, all elements are self-inverse in fact (I've edited).

Comment: Then the element $gh$ is self-inverse, which means that $(gh)(gh)=e$

Comment: Ah ok! So it's a direct property, and no algebraic proof is needed. Thank you.

Comment: For such groups with this property see also the posts here (it is a popular homework question), e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238171/prove-that-if-g2-e-for-all-g-in-g-then-g-is-abelian).

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun It's not a published book, it's the book accompanying a course from my university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $g$ and $h$ be elements of a group $G$, where **all elements are self-inverse**.
>
> ...
>
> We can then write: $(gh)(gh) = e$.
>
> By what operation do we reach this last step?

All elements are self-inverse, and it's a group, so $gh\in G$, so $gh$ is self-inverse, in other words $ghgh=e$.

Comment: This is the group axiom G1 closure, indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the original version of the question, before the extra condition "where all elements are self-inverse" set in. So, suppose there are $g,h\in G$ such that $g^2=h^2=e$; then $(hg)(gh)=e$, and hence $(gh)(gh)=e$ only if $hg=gh$, namely $h\in C_G(g)$ (or, equivalently, $g\in C_G(h)$).